# Change ion-progress-bar background color

Tags: ionic4

I recently switched to Ionic 4 and I'm having some troubles with the SCSS.

I have a very basic home page :

```
<ion-content padding>

  <div class="quizz-progress ion-text-center">
    <ion-progress-bar value="0.4"></ion-progress-bar>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

And I would like to set a custom background color for my progress bar without using primary colors set in variable.scss

I saw while running the app that this is the result HTML inside the **ion-progress-bar**

```
<div class="progress" style="transform: scaleX(0.4);"></div>
<div class="progress-buffer-bar" style="transform: scaleX(1);"></div>
```

These elements are inside a shadow root, and I understood that using a simple `background-color: red` in my SCSS wouldn't work.

Here is what I did in my SCSS file :

```
.quizz-progress{
    ion-progress-bar{
        .progress{
            --background-color: var(--ion-color-primary);
        }
        .progress-buffer-bar{
            --background-color: var(--ion-color-light);
        }
    }
}
```

But this has no effect. How could I change the color of the progress bar without using the `color` attribute ? Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try like this

```
  <div class="quizz-progress ion-text-center">
    <ion-progress-bar value="0.5"></ion-progress-bar>
  </div>

.quizz-progress {
 ion-progress-bar {
    --background: green;
    --buffer-background: red;
    --progress-background: black;
  }
}
```

here [CSS Custom Properties](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/progress-bar)